# RecyclerView Proguard error while running espresso tests

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, proguard, android-support-library

I am encountering the following error when trying to use proguard in espresso:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method findViewHolderForPosition(I)Landroid/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView$v; in class Landroid/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView; or its super classes (declaration of 'android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView' appears in /data/app/com.stacklighting.stackandroidappdev-1/base.apk)
at android.support.test.espresso.contrib.RecyclerViewActions$ActionOnItemAtPositionViewAction.perform(RecyclerViewActions.java:288)
at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction$1.run(ViewInteraction.java:144)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:428)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
```

My proguard file is:

```
-dontwarn org.hamcrest.**
-dontwarn android.test.**
-dontwarn android.support.test.**
-keep class org.hamcrest.** { *; }
-keep class org.junit.** { *; }
-dontwarn org.junit.**
-keep class junit.** { *; }
-dontwarn junit.**
-keep class sun.misc.** { *; }
-dontwarn sun.misc.**
-keep class com.squareup.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.squareup.**

-keep class android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
```

In my dependencies, the RecyclerView I am using is

```
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.0.0'
```

Comment: try to use `-keep class android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView { *; }`

Comment: Have you found a solution ? Can you paste your build.gradle file ?
I had to add ``-keep class android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView { *; }`` inside my proguard-rules.pro instead of proguard-test-rules.pro.